# Swift 2 NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL Cannot invoke with an argument list of type

Tags: swift2, xcode7

Cant seem to get the following code to compile with Xcode 7, I get error "Cannot invoke 'dataTaskWithURL' with an argument list of type"

Looks like completionHandler is no longer optional, cant figure out how to rewrite the following code. Any help appreciated, Thanks

```
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    var task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            var error: NSError?

            var jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSArray
            // Do Stuff
        }
    }

    task!.resume()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler is throwing the following error:

> /Users/Xcode/Desktop/fdsfsdfds/fdsfsdfds/AppDelegate.swift:24:28:
>   Cannot invoke 'dataTaskWithURL' with an argument list of type '(NSURL,
>   (_, _, _) **throws** -> Void)'

In the *completionHandler* you're not catching the exceptions that `JSONObjectWithData` may eventually throw. Therefore the compiler infers that you're trying to propagate the exception which would require that the completionHandler had the following signature:

```
(NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) throws -> Void
```

This does not match with the actual *completionHandler* `dataTaskWithURL` is expecting and thus the error.

To solve this issue simply wrap your call to `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` is a do/catch statement as follows to handle the error:

```
do {
    var jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSArray
    // Do Stuff

} catch {
    // handle error
}
```

For more informations about error handling in Swift2 refer to the prerelease documentation available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)

Comment: Updated with some more additional info explaining the reasons of the problem.

Comment: I add throws and do { try } catch {} , but still prompt error "Cannot invoke 'dataTaskWithURL' with an argument list of type '(NSURL, (_, _, _) throws -> Void)'" - [Xcode 7 beta2]

Answer (score 2):

As of Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7 beta 6), use `dataTaskWithURL()` like this:

```
var task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {
   (data, response, error) -> Void in

   :
})
task.resume()
```

To use `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` within the completion handler, you will also need catch errors:

```
    do {
        var jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSArray
        // Do Stuff
    } catch {
        // handle error
    }
```

Comment: This post also helped me out, https://jeremywsherman.com/blog/2015/06/17/using-swift-throws-with-completion-callbacks/

Answer (score 1):

```
let url : String = String(format: "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/news/v3/content/nyt/all/720.json?api-key=%@",apiKey)
        let url1: NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
      let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task1 = session.dataTaskWithURL(url1, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
                        do {
                         if data == nil {
                    return
                }
                else
                {

                let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                self.dict = jsonData;
                self.array1 = (self.dict.objectForKey("results") as? NSMutableArray)!
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.table.reloadData()
                }

                }

            } catch {

            }

        })
```

Comment: Please explain your code in your answer. So, any one can understand what you have done so far.